# Dashed strokes to draw polygons in p5.js

Tags: p5.js

I have a piece of code running with createjs. It draws the polygons to the canvas with dashed strokes and adjusts the offset every time so that the dashed strokes appear to be moving along a path. I am doing this with `setStrokeDash()` command in createjs. Is there any equivalent command which does the same thing in p5.js?
The working code in createjs in given below:

```html
<head>
    <script src="easeljs-0.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var stage, polygon0 = false;
    var dashCmd;

    function init()
    {
         stage = new createjs.Stage("demoCanvas");          

         polygon0 = stage.addChild(new createjs.Shape());
         dashCmd = polygon0.graphics.setStrokeDash([7,3]).command;

         polygon0.graphics.beginStroke("black");
         polygon0.graphics.moveTo(508,564).lineTo(516,564).lineTo(775, 552).lineTo(508, 564);

         createjs.Ticker.timingMode = createjs.Ticker.RAF;

    }

    function tick(event)
    {
         dashCmd.offset++;
         stage.update(event);
    }
    </script>
</head>

<body onload="init();">
    <canvas id="demoCanvas" width="1200" height="1200"></canvas>
</body>
```

Comment: I think it would be good to provide minimum reproducible codes which fulfill your need in createjs. In that way people have better ideas.

Answer (score 2):

**P5.JS** doesn't include that but you can still use the **javascript** syntaxs to do that:
`canvas.drawingContext.setLineDash([5, 5]);`

***P. S***: *Your canvas must be a global variable like that:*

```
let canvas;

function setup() {
  canvas = createCanvas();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, P5.js does not include this functionality. You can peruse [the P5.js reference](https://p5js.org/reference/) to be sure.

You would probably need to implement this functionality yourself. Or you could check out libraries like [p5.scribble](https://github.com/generative-light/p5.scribble.js).