# Draw a dashed stroke rectangle

Tags: p5.js

Is there an easy way to do this? I though there was something like "strokeStyle" but apparently there's no such thing...

So, would drawing a series of short lines be the only way to go?

Comment: https://github.com/processing/p5.js/issues/3336#issuecomment-441457612 [Dashed strokes to draw polygons in p5.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50425367/dashed-strokes-to-draw-polygons-in-p5-js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might already be familiar [`setLineDash()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/setLineDash): you can access p5's Canvas context via [`drawingContext`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/drawingContext)

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(300, 300);
  drawingContext.setLineDash([6]);
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  rect(100, 100, 100, 100);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.7.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @George! So THAT's why p5 doesn't have such thing...